# wolkenkit: DATABASE access & backup

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, wolkenkit

I just cloned wolkenkit-todomvc from [repo](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-todomvc). I tried to execute it with "wolkenkit start" then

1. docker exec -it todomvc-mongodb mongo admin
2. show dbs

and got

```
{
   "operationTime" : Timestamp(1514838628, 1),
   "ok" : 0,
   "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0 }",
   "code" : 13,
   "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
}
```

My questions are

1. What is the user and password for access these container's database?
2. how do I access Mongodb and Postgres data from docker container?. such as

   - db.todos.find()
   - SELECT * FROM todos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To execute [wolkenkit-todomvc](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-todomvc) you first need to install [wolkenkit](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit). The concrete steps depend on your platform. Refer to [installing wolkenkit on macOS](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/latest/getting-started/installing-wolkenkit/installing-on-macos/), [installing wolkenkit on Linux](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/latest/getting-started/installing-wolkenkit/installing-on-linux/), or [installing wolkenkit on Windows](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/latest/getting-started/installing-wolkenkit/installing-on-windows/).

Then run the application by running the following command, as described in the [quick start](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-todomvc#quick-start):

```
$ wolkenkit start
```

If you want to access the database explicitly, as I assume from reading your question, e.g. to create a backup, you need to use the `wolkenkit` user. The password is the so-called "shared key", which is shown when running `wolkenkit start`. If you want to, you can also [set the shared key manually](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/1.2.0/reference/using-the-cli/protecting-an-application/), otherwise it is created randomly.

Please note that there are two databases, as you can see [from the architecture of wolkenkit](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/1.2.0/getting-started/understanding-wolkenkit/architecture/), one using PostgreSQL to store the events, one using MongoDB to store the denormalized lists. In the events database, there is only one large table for all the events. This is the raw data. If you are interested in the interpreted views, take a look at the MongoDB.

If you want to create a backup, backup the event store, as this is the single source of truth. The read database can be rebuilt from the event store, but not vice-versa.

Hope this helps.

*PS: Please note that I am one of the authors of [wolkenkit](https://www.wolkenkit.io/).*

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. You have clarified what I actually want.

Comment: Hello Golo, I am not able to connect with mongodb  and postgress. I am using  docker exec -it todomvc-mongodb mongo -user wolkenkit -p 576085646aa24f4670b929f0c47032ebf149e48f admin. It shows following result : 2018-08-14T11:48:20.592+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :

Comment: Could you please turn this into a question of its own?